# How Could I Add Blood Particle Effect After I killed An Enemy?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an Enemys That Move Left And Right With A HealthBar ***But How Could I add Particles When The Enemy Dies Like Blood Particles When The enemy Is Killed it appears and falls down and dispears?***

Example: >>> [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/4adb4d0945a24e8ce68c4cc202fc56ef) I killed the enemy and its deleted how could I make load blood particles same position as the enemy that just died

heres my enemy class

```
 class enemys:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,end):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.esright = [pygame.image.load("esright1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright3.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright4.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright5.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright6.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright7.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright8.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright9.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright10.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright11.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright12.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright13.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright14.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright15.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright16.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esright17.png"),
                              ]
            self.esleft = [pygame.image.load("esleft1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft3.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft4.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft5.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft6.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft7.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft8.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft9.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft10.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft11.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft12.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft13.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft14.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft15.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft16.png"),
            pygame.image.load("esleft17.png"),
                              ]
            self.esright = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//3,image.get_height()//3)) for image in self.esright]
            self.esleft = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//3,image.get_height()//3)) for image in self.esleft]
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.anim_index = 0
            self.distance = 80
            self.speed = 8
            self.vel = 3
            self.path = [x,end]
            self.Walking_index = 0
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            COOLDOWN = 30
            # enemys health
            self.health = 10
            self.visible = True

        # this makes the enemy move right and left
        def draw(self,window):
            self.move()
            if self.Walking_index + 1 >= 33:
                self.Walking_index = 0
            if self.vel > 0:
                window.blit(self.esright[self.Walking_index//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.Walking_index += 1
            else:
                window.blit(self.esleft[self.Walking_index//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.Walking_index += 1

    # this moves the enemy left and right
        def move(self):
            if self.visible:
                if self.vel > 0:
                   if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                       self.x += self.vel
                   else:
                       self.vel = self.vel * -1
                       self.Walking_index = 0
                else:
                   if self.x - self.vel >  self.path[0]:
                       self.x += self.vel
                   else:
                       self.vel = self.vel * -1
                       self.Walking_index = 0
                    # the hit box for the enemy the health
                pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 70, 10)) # NEW
                pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 70 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
                self.hitbox = (self.x + 47, self.y + 31, 50, 72)


    # THIS PART MAKES  the enemy not scroll with the player
        def scroll(self,sx, sy):
            self.x += sx
            self.y += sy
            self.path[0] += sx
            self.path[1] += sx
```

heres when the enemys health bar reaches 0 the enemy gets deleted how can I add particles when its deleted? blood particles that drop from the enemys position

```
            # enemys 1
            for bullet in bullets:
                if bullet.rect.colliderect(enemys2.hitbox):
                    if enemys2.health > -5:
                        enemys2.health -= 1
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                        hitesound.play()
                            # this function calss the -5 text appearing and dispearing on my screen
                        minusenemyhealthtext()
                    else:
                        for oe in range(len(enemyings)-1,-1,-1):
                                deathsound.play()
                                del enemyings[oe]
```

Comment: Creating a [mcve] will make it easier to help you. How do you remove your enemy object? When you remove it, you could create a blood_splatter object in the original position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are your options:

1. Get a GIF, split it to multiple images, and just display each of those images one after another. Make all of that in a class.
2. Make a class (blood class) that would draw make instances of another class (particle class) that just moves outwards and disappears after a while.

I am not going to write the code out for you, you must write it yourself, but that is how you do it.